# How to make curly homemade flat noodles

Tags: egg-noodles

I know how to make egg noodles, and I either roll them out or use my pasta machine with the fettuccine cutter.  This gives me flat egg noodles.
I like the curly ones that I buy at the store for some dishes.
Is there a technique I can use to make my homemade noodles curly when I want them to be curly?
To clarify, I would like them curly at the edges, but still mostly flat, similar to most of the wide egg noodles in the store.

Comment: Do you mean curls on both sides of the noodle, yet alternate? So that the middle of the noodle still lays flat?

Comment: At the industrial level I think the curly noodles are made by having flaps drag along the sides to warp the noodles as they're extruded. I'm not sure that it's something you can do easily at home.

Answer (score 1):

You can curl them at home with a little effort.. Cut your pasta into ribbons and then cut those ribbons into smaller ribbons. Let them dry for just a little while (not so dry that they have lost all moisture) and then pull them gently, twisting them slightly as you do. Let them dry again to set and you should have what you're looking for.

Comment: I would think that it'd be easier to leave them as long ribbons , as you could twist the whole thing, let it dry some more, then cut them shorter once they've dried enough to hold their shape..  (but I've never tried it myself)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this **Lasagna Doppia Riccia** at the bottom?

[image: Lasagna Doppia Riccia]

Make sheets of pasta, cut to size then use a butter paddle or [gnocchi board](http://thecheesemakingworkshop.com.au/store/gnocchi-board/) to indent just the edges.

[image: gnocchi board]

For all sorts of pasta shapes, see [Manu's Menu](http://www.manusmenu.com/tips/techniques/pasta-and-gnocchi) website